# Accessing non-current state_machine states

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

I've got six states on my `order.rb` file. I want to access each of the non-current states to populate a drop-down menu so the state can readily be changed. I've come up with this. The function doesn't work, obviously, and the states are `written_like_this`.

```
<% order.state_paths.to_states.each do |state| %>
    <%= link_to(state.to_s, order.adjust(state)) %>
<% end %>
```

I'd like to write a catch-all method too that interprets the clicks from the above menu and transitions the record to the selected state. Something like (pseudo-code):

```
def adjust(state)
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @order.state = state
end
```

Any thoughts would be great. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

```
def adjust
  session[:return_to] ||= request.referer
  @doc = Doc.find(params[:id])
  state = params[:state]
  respond_to do |format|
    @doc.update_attribute(:state, state)
    @doc.create_activity state.to_sym, owner: current_user
    format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: "#{@doc.title} has now been #{state}." }
    format.json { render json: @doc }
  end
end
```

And I've made the buttons like this:

```
<% activity.trackable.state_paths.events.each do |s| %>
  <%= link_to(s.to_s.titlecase, adjust_path(s, activity.trackable)) %>
<% end %>
```

Boom.